# Offset 2D-Matrix: equal spacing in pattern

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Let's first take a look at the Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

**My problem:**

I just cannot figure out how to **change the spacing between the horizontal lines**. This spacing is a little bit too wide, as you can see compared to the vertical lines.

This is how I implemented the pattern of UIButtons:

```
func buildBoard(){
        for i in 0...8{
            for j in 0...8{
                rowBtnArr.append(setupBtn(x: i, y: j))
            }
        }
}

func setupBtn( x: Int, y: Int)->UIButton{
        let btnSize = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10) //40
        let buffer = 1
        if(y%2==0){ //even lines: normal
            button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x*btnSize, y: y*btnSize, width: btnSize-buffer, height: btnSize-buffer))
        }else{ //odd lines: shift by 1/2 button width
            button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x*btnSize+(btnSize/2), y: y*btnSize, width: btnSize-buffer, height: btnSize-buffer))
        }
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        //unimportant color and target lines are left out
        return button
}
```

Thanks for any help!
SwiftHobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one thing you have to consider is that because you are offsetting the rows every even row, there is more space vertically because the peak height of your circles matches up with the intersection of circles above it. So what I would do is subtract some number to the btnSize before you multiply it by y. This should tighten the y-spacing.

```
func setupBtn( x: Int, y: Int)->UIButton{
        let btnSize = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10) //40
        let buffer = 1
        if(y%2==0){ //even lines: normal
            button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x*btnSize, y: y*(btnSize-1), width: btnSize-buffer, height: btnSize-buffer))
        }else{ //odd lines: shift by 1/2 button width
            button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x*btnSize+(btnSize/2), y: y*(btnSize-1), width: btnSize-buffer, height: btnSize-buffer))
        }
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        //unimportant color and target lines are left out
        return button
}
```

This way the y-spacing is closer than the x-spacing, accounting for the mismatch I was talking about earlier. You need to experiment with the y-spacing to get the visual difference you want, so my correction above might be weird looking as well.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want this effect:
[image]

I use your code and make some changes, and use a Array to cache all buttons's frame like blow:

```
// user a Array to cache all frames
lazy var framesMatrix: [[CGRect]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: CGRect.zero, count: 9), count: 9)


func setupBtn( x: Int, y: Int)->UIButton{
    
    let btnCount = 10
    let buffer: CGFloat = 1
    let btnSize = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - CGFloat(btnCount - 1) * buffer) / CGFloat(btnCount)
    var button: UIButton = UIButton()
    
    if y % 2 == 0 {
        if y == 0 {
            let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(x)*(btnSize+buffer), y: CGFloat(y)*btnSize, width: btnSize, height: btnSize)
            framesMatrix[x][y] = frame
            button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        } else {
            let lastFrame = framesMatrix[x][y-1]
            // Here is the change
            let newCenterY = lastFrame.midY + sqrt(3.0) * 0.5 * (btnSize+buffer);

            let frame = CGRect(x: lastFrame.minX - btnSize * 0.5 , y: newCenterY - btnSize * 0.5, width: btnSize, height: btnSize);
            framesMatrix[x][y] = frame
            button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        }
        
    } else {
        let lastFrame = framesMatrix[x][y-1]
         
        // Here is the change
        let newCenterY = lastFrame.midY + sqrt(3.0) * 0.5 * (btnSize+buffer);
        
        let frame = CGRect(x: lastFrame.midX + buffer * 0.5, y: newCenterY - btnSize * 0.5 , width: btnSize, height: btnSize);
        framesMatrix[x][y] = frame
        button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        
    }
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    //unimportant color and target lines are left out
    return button
}
```